# Best way to compare *nix timestamps in bash

Tags: linux, bash, timestamp, comparison

I want to compare two Unix/Linux timestamps as fast as possible in bash:

```
    TIMESTAMP_A=1472680800
    TIMESTAMP_B=1458687600

    if [[ ${TIMESTAMP_A} -lt ${TIMESTAMP_B} ]]; then
            echo "Timestamp A is younger!";
    else
            echo "Timestamp B is younger!";
    fi
```

Does my solution always work or do I need to take care of some special cases?

Comment: It's fast enough. If you need it to be faster, `bash` is the wrong language for whatever it is you are doing.

Comment: Do it in pure C

Comment: You might want to confirm that the A is greater than B and if not, switch the values so you always get a positive value. Other range checking might be suitable too. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the times are Epoch time (seconds since 1970-01-01), you would get the correct result.

If time is not in Epoch form, you can convert the time in Epoch first, using `date`:

```
date -d '<your_reference_time>' '+%s'
```